# WordPress styling working on default page, but not specific post page

Tags: wordpress, styles, default

So, I have this WordPress [blog](http://jordanphillipcarter.com/wordpress/).

My latest post has some html and css styling. It works fine on the default page...but click the post from the left menu bar and all my styling disappears...What gives? It appears my images are not loading...do I need to change the file path?

```html
<div class="GlobeContainer">
   <div class="circle" id="circle">
      <img class="snowfall" src="images/SnowfallMidground.png" alt="snow" />
   </div>
   <img src="images/snowglobe.jpg" alt="snow globe" />
</div>
```

It appears my spans in the blog post are being styled to green and blue as expected, so it must be an issue with the location of the image...

Comment: there is confusion in 'some html and css styling'. every website has that.

Comment: Please show your code and it's location as per wordpress functions and templates. Initial guess is that the issue is related to the different templates for the main page/blogroll vs. single post template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add full path for every images

```html
<div class="GlobeContainer">
  <div id="circle2" class="circle"><img alt="snow" src="http://jordanphillipcarter.com/wordpress/images/SnowfallMidground.png" class="snowfall"></div>
  <p><img alt="snow globe" src="http://jordanphillipcarter.com/wordpress/images/snowglobe.jpg"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the `DOM` values for the snowfall image you will see that WordPress generates the following for the main page:
`"http://jordanphillipcarter.com/wordpress/images/SnowfallMidground.png"`
And the following for the Single Post:
`"http://jordanphillipcarter.com/wordpress/2015/12/25/wordpress/images/SnowfallMidground.png"`.

It appears (without reviewing your Single Post Template) that your Single Post Page prefixes the additional media setting (from the admin panel - `Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders`) to the entered value.

Have you tried uploading the image using WordPress, allowing it to manage the path and then add your markup separately?

Comment: No, I did not try that. I wanted to try adding everything on my own through HTML and CSS as a sort of experiment. I could see how your way would have benefits in some scenarios, though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

calling image src dynamically,

Ex:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img.jpg"/>
```

calling post image,

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>
```